# MongoDB query by date gives current date always

Tags: mongodb, java-8

When ever I query based on the date field I get all the attributes correct but date field is always current date. Why is that so? I am using java 8 spring with MongoRepository implementation. In the collection it is Date field and in java object also it is Date.

I changed it to LocalDateTime but still gives current date. Changing it to ZonedDateTime does not work as java does not automatically converted DB date object to ZonedDateTime.

How can I query mongoDB using date which will return me the actual date value in database and not current Date.

Java DB Object:

```
@Document(collection = "XXX")
public class XXX{
@Field(value= "ts")
private Date timestamp;
```

MongoDB document:

```
{ 
"_id" : ObjectId("--------"), 
"ts" : ISODate("2016-11-29T21:22:00.000+0000") 
}
```

Repository:

```
@Query(value = "{'regId': ?0, 'ts': {'$lte': ?1}}")
Page<T> findAllByRegId(ObjectId regId, Date timeStamp, Pageable pageable);
```

Result I get:

```
id= same Id as above
ts = 2016-11-29T16:22:00.000Z
```

ts is always returned in current timestamp, but in DB it has value 2016-11-29T21:22.

Comment: Can you add an example pls ? Easier to follow

Comment: Can you post an example of your query?  MongoDB stores dates in the ISODate format.

Comment: i am not storing the data, i am trying to fetch the data so I think it should give me the same date as there in DB irrespective of the timezone.

Comment: that's not true it's based on the driver. Also can you check the milliseconds value in the returned date. The printing can happen in local time zone.My guess you've the right milliseconds value which is your db value and it's just while printing the date is shown in local time zone

Comment: I am using this driver mongo-java-driver-2.13.3

Comment: can you debug the milliseconds in the date value pls ?

Comment: millisecond value is same which means only date part is getting converted to current date but time is same. How can i resolve this?

Comment: milliseconds is from epoch. It includes date and time. There is nothing to resolve here. It's all good just ignore the printed value. What are you planning to do with that date you get from db ?

Comment: I have to change the date (which is ISODate) to the timezone of the site where user is present. As I am not getting the correct date from the query , my final result is wrong.

Comment: you can change the date to java 8 instant and zoned date time and or local date time based on your need. Do that everything will be fine

Comment: I tried changing date to LocalDateTime but get same problem. With ZonedDateTime i get error as my driver is not able to convert Date to ZonedDateTime. Can you provide some code snippet ?

Comment: What is your zone ?

Comment: America/NewYork

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's problem with the java util date toString representation which shows the value in the local time zone when printing.

So for Java 8 you can switch them to local date time from the util date.

```
LocalDateTime datetime = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(ts.toInstant(), ZoneId.of("America/New_York"))
```